# Jenkins create a view of build jobs where built from branch

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In jenkins, I created a view of builds jobs. I want to specify only builds from a particular branch. Is there way to parameterized or set the branch name so it will only return the latest builds of the branch name provided?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with the [View Job Filters](https://plugins.jenkins.io/view-job-filters/) plugin. From the description:

> This plug-in provides more ways to include/exclude jobs from a view, including filtering by SCM path [...]

E.g., this will select all trunk-related jobs:

[image]

Comment: There is no filter by branch

Comment: There is a `Regular Expression Job Filter` that allows to match a regular expression against `Job SCM configuration`. This does not do the trick?

Comment: I added an example config screenshot that does works for me.

Comment: I am not able to install this plugin due to permission. So I am not able to test for now.